# Cron running 2hrs early

Tags: raspbian, cron

I checked the time on my pi to make sure it's right by running date and I believe I set my cron job correctly, I wish for it to run at 9am and 9pm, but they're running instead at 7am and 7pm.

Here's my cron tab:

0 9,21 * * * sh /home/pi/.myscript.sh

What I am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron is very sensitive to large time shifts, in this case, i'll bet timezone, so just try to restart it.

Type:

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```

That might fix it.

Comment: I've given this a try, will see how it goes. Also, `/etc/init.d/crond restart` doesn't work for me, but `/etc/init.d/cron restart` does. I'm guessing this refers to the same thing?

Comment: Yes, Debian and Ubuntu use cron instead of crond, i didn't knew your system, but I should have assumed that you would be using Raspbian. I'll edit it.

Comment: It could also be related to differences in timezones. do you have timezones configured for your profile? (look for TZ=.... in your .profile) Check also /etc/rc.conf and look for the TIMEZONE variable

Comment: yep, this did the trick.